# Spring login mapping being called on non authorized pages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Whenever I visit my index page or any pages where you need not login to view, my login controller is being called...

Here is my security config..

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and().
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/", "/index", "/error", "/login", "/register", "/catalog","css/*", "js/*", "img/*", "svg/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/management/api/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), MOD.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", true)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenValiditySeconds((int)TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(21))
                .key("xyz")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("logout")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
```

My console log, it's throwing like 3 errors on visiting index....

```
Completed initialization in 4 ms
2020-07-29 20:41:14.403 ERROR 11288 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "login": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/login.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/login.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
```

Well, what I am trying to use is create a register and login page side by side, so user can either login or choose to register on the page. If the user registers an object is made and entered into the db via the repo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=yyz1LsQaB2qWB785wbu_yzKH2SndBnt5piypxQkmfSUMGshENwFIbOpHfkLC2pmS" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E3E8934C-235A-4B0E-825A-35A08381A191/abn/main.css?attr=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2xvZ2lu"/></head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in...!</h2>
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="login-username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="login-password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="remember-me">Remember me ?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me" class="form-control">
                </p>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form class="form-signin" method="post" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${User}">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2>
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                    <input th:field="*{username}" type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </p>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{isAccountNonExpired}" th:value="true" id="isAccountNonExpired" name="isAccountNonExpired" class="form-control"  required>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{isAccountNonLocked}" th:value="true" id="isAccountNonLocked" name="isAccountNonLocked" class="form-control"  required>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{isCredentialsNonExpired}" th:value="true" id="isCredentialsNonExpired" name="isCredentialsNonExpired" class="form-control"  required>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{isEnabled}" th:value="true" id="isEnabled" name="isEnabled" class="form-control"  required>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{roles}" th:value="USER" id="roles" name="roles" class="form-control"  required>
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{permissions}" th:value="" id="permissions" name="permissions" class="form-control"  required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Above is my html page.

Answer (score 0):

In your login part of your Thymeleaf template you specify:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
```

and in your sinning you specify:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${User}">
```

There are also other missing Thymeleaf tags in your login part. For example:

```
<input type="text" id="login-username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
```

vs

```
<input th:field="*{username}" type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
```

This seems like problem which threw Thymeleaf error for me. Also your confirm password HTML element of sinning part doesn't seem to use any Thymeleaf tag at all -> probably also unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I was trying to parse empty values in the permissions.

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{permissions}" th:value="" id="permissions" name="permissions" class="form-control"  required>
```

changing value to value="none" fixed the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your issue ? Is it working without proposed changes in my answer ? If no please specify correct answer for future reader's